# Que tem que ver a peneira com vaidade e aves de rapina?

Tags: etimologia

Ao ouvir hoje [esta canção](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZCYrAlfU0E) dei-me conta de uma coisa que eu sempre soube mas a que nunca prestei atenção: uma [peneira](http://www.aulete.com.br/peneira) é no seu sentido primário uma espécie de crivo (ver figura à esquerda), mas no plural, [peneiras](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/peneira), parece-me que não no Brasil, significa vaidade. Um [peneireiro](http://www.aulete.com.br/peneireiro) pode ser alguém que faz ou vende peneiras; mas pode também ser [uma de várias espécies de falcão](http://www.avesdeportugal.info/faltin.html).

Ora como é que o nome dum utensílio para, bem, peneirar, veio a significar vaidade, supondo que foi esse o percurso? E como é a ave de rapina veio a partilhar o nome com quem faz peneiras?

[image]

Comment: As tuas peneiras da foto são peças de museu ? (rs)

Comment: @Centaurus Imagino que sim. Já ninguém peneira coisa alguma. Eu venho de uma família de agricultores, e quando era criança tínhamos em casa uma muito parecida com a da esquerda. Ainda me lembro de a usarmos para separar o feijão da palha.

Comment: Ainda peneiramos aqui em casa.  Na cozinha, a cozinheira faz uso de uma peneira ou um coador com relativa frequência.

Comment: @Centaurus Em Inglaterra, seguindo a boa tradição do português no estrangeiro, eu cozia o meu pão. Ao princípio peneirava a farinha com um [coador (não chamaria a isto peneira)](http://www.nedo.com.br/imagens/847.jpg). Depois cheguei à conclusão que não era necessário.

Comment: Jacinto,  não sei se estou certo ou errado, mas na minha cabeça um coador é usado para separar sólidos de um líquido.  Já a peneira pode ser para qualquer coisa, separar partículas maiores de partículas menores, peneirar só um tipo de pó para que ele fique bem solto (ex, açúcar ou areia usada na construção) ou separar sólidos de líquidos.

Comment: @Centaurus Para mim *coador* também é isso; por exemplo, para escorrer massas depois de cozinhadas. Mas peneira para mim é só para sólidos, o que está de acordo com o Aulete e Michaelis. Enquanto o coador é frequentemente afunilado, a peneira tem fundo plano, imagino que para melhor espalhar a farinha ou o que for por uma superfície maior. Já para areia eu usaria *crivo*. Pensando bem acho que era *crivo* que nós chamávamos à minha peneira da esquerda. Mas o Aulete e Michaelis dizem que peneira pode ser crivo. Em Inglaterra peneirava com coador porque não tinha peneira.

Comment: @Centaurus as peneiras do Jacinto (heh) têm um aspeto miserável, de facto; mas em casa da minha avó há uma igualzinha à da esquerda, por isso não são necessariamente «de museu».

Comment: Eu acho que estás a levar a palavra *peneira* demasiado à letra. Na minha opinião, relaciona-se com aves (de rapina ou não) porque as aves têm **penas**. A questão da vaidade... pensa no pavão e no que ele faz com as penas e acho que já tens aí a resposta. Aliás, pensa no significado de **peneirento**.

Answer (score 2):

Por todas as voltas que esta pergunta já deu e porque ninguém mais parece querer pegar nisto, reformulo o que pude apurar.

> **DISCLAIMER**: As fontes que encontrei são escassas e há um certo obscurantismo sobre a origem de alguns dos termos indicados, ainda
>   assim, penso ser válido estabelecer algumas relações de causalidade.

Então, sobre ***peneira***:

Definição [[Priberam]](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/peneira):

> Espécie de caixa circular com fundo de seda, crina ou palhinha entrançada para joeirar farinha ou outras substâncias.

Etimologia:

- É *obscura* de acordo com o Priberam, mas [uma pesquisa no Google](http://origemdapalavra.com.br/site/palavras/peneira/) parece indicar que a origem será de *panaria* (cesta, em latim), que por sua vez deriva de *panis* (pão, em latim).
- Há um reforço desta ideia expresso no livro *De onde vem as palavras: origens e curiosidades da língua portuguesa*, por Deonísio da Silva, no que refere a definição de *crivo* (um sinónimo de peneira) - [link Google Books](https://books.google.pt/books?id=P3JxBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT303&lpg=PT303&dq=peneira%20latim&source=bl&ots=uZ-NhWts5b&sig=QcqNA_QSkpP4rbRmcalFre7ZUCI&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLt-motLjLAhVE1ywKHYz7COwQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=peneira%20latim&f=false).

Sobre ***peneiras***:

Definição [[Priberam]](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/peneira):

> [Informal]  Demonstração de vaidade ou presunção. = PROSÁPIA

Etimologia:

Uma vez mais, de acordo com o Priberam, não é clara a origem da palavra.
Há, contudo, vários indícios que aprecem apontar no sentido de **não ter relação** com a origem de *peneira*:

- Em ornitologia, **peneirar** é  *«[a] técnica de caça na qual a ave paira no ar e observa os arredores a procura de alguma presa»* - [Wiki Aves](http://www.wikiaves.com/dicionario_wiki_aves). Daqui se explicaria o porquê haver aves de rapina, nomeadamente o [**peneireiro**-comum](http://www.avesdeportugal.info/faltin.html) e o [gavião-**peneira**](http://www.wikiaves.com.br/gaviao-peneira), com nomes comuns que nos remetem para esta etimologia.

Por sugestão do **@Jacinto**, fica também [referência para o Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=peneirar) que relaciona ***peneirar*** (vôo característico de algumas aves) com **mover-se como quem *peneira***. Daqui parece uma vez mais haver uma sugestão de relação entre *peneirar* - forma de se mover -  e *peneiras* - vaidade.

Digo, portanto que o *peneireiro* (ave) ou o *peneireiro* (homem que faz peneiras) serão portanto apenas **homónimos**, que provavelmente tiveram evoluções distintas, quer por via popular, quer por via erudita, sendo que cada uma destas palavras provavelmente originou de raízes distintas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36838/discussion-on-answer-by-joum-que-tem-que-ver-a-peneira-com-vaidade-e-aves-de-rap).

Comment: Ficou misturado "peneiras" (vaidade) com "peneirar" (planar em caça).

Comment: Joum, vê [peneirar aqui](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=peneirar). É relevante. Já viste alguém a manusear uma peneira? Se não, pega num prato grande (à falta de peneira) com uma mão de cada lado, e movimenta-o repetidamente da direita para a esquerda ou em percurso elíptico, e observa o teu corpo ao espelho.Vê que todos os dicionários dizem que peneirar, em todos os sentidos, vem de *peneira + ar*. Palavras homónimas de origens diferente aparecem nos dicionários em entradas diferentes [exemplo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/pena).

Comment: Mas peneira e peneiras também têm entradas diferentes no Priberam, não? Aliás peneiras (plural de peneira) é uma coisa e peneiras (vaidade, etc...) será outra, citando a mesma fonte onde foste buscar o teu exemplo. A mim, faz-me alguma confusão que *peneiras* no singular não possa ter outro significado que esteja relacionado com *pena*, *peneirar* (como as aves), mas a verdade é que não encontro evidências disso.

Comment: Estava a falar de *peneirar* no Michaelis, que inclui na mesma entrada os significados *peneirar com peneira; saracotear-se, bambolear-se; e pairar (aves)*. Mas também no Priberam *peneiras* aparece como significado 8 de *peneira*; já em pena, encontras *pena1* e *pena2*, com numerações independentes. De qualquer modo, eu quis principalmente chamar a atenção para *peneirar* no Michaelis, que me parece muito interessante. (na próxima começa o teu comentário com @jacinto para eu ser notificado; para ti não é aqui necessário, porque o autor da resposta/pergunta é sempre notificado.)

Comment: Tens razão que nenhum dicionário relaciona *peneira* com *pena*. Mas o Michaelis relaciona [*peneirar (aves)* com *peneira*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=peneirar) (2ª vez que te indico este link). E também relaciona *bambolear-se* com *peneira*. Poderá estar aqui uma ligação a vaidade.

Comment: @Jacinto adicionei a tua referência. No entanto não consegui apurar mais nada sobre a ligação a _vaidade_. Se te surgir, tem a bondade de editares como te aprouver! ;)

Comment: Joum, fui ver o nome do raio do pássaro em espanhol, e nem mais: [*cernícalo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8MBEPpQ), do latim *cerniculum*, que significa *crivo, peneira*. E [*cerner*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8MBEPpQ) significa: 1) peneirar (farinha, etc.); e 7) voar à peneireiro, sem sair do sítio. A [Wikipédia espanhola explica que o *cernículo* faz isso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falco_tinnunculus)

Comment: @Jacinto Pronto! Está explicado! :D estabelecida a pertinência, resta saber como enquadrar isso à luz do explicado, uma vez que é de espanhol que estamos a falar. Sugere edição!

Comment: Joum, a resposta é tua. Eu trouxe-te informação que me parece relevante. Agora faz com ela o que te parecer melhor. Entretanto tive a ver um [video de um peneireiro a peneirar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_03F49thJ6s) e outro de uma [senhora a peneirara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siJ8QmP4Zx0).

Comment: Joum, creio que encontrei a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

### Peneireiro (falcão)

A meu ver, o peneireiro chama-se assim pelo seu hábito de “permanecer voando parado sobre determinado ponto no solo” ([Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peneireiro-vulgar)). A isto chama-se ***peneirar*** ([Michaelis 7](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/peneirar/)), provavelmente pela semelhança com o movimento da peneira ou da pessoa que manuseia a peneira: ao agitar a peneira lateralmente, o corpo da pessoa bamboleia para compensar. Aliás, *peneirar* significa também ‘bambolear, saracotear’ ([Michaelis 4](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/peneirar/)).

Uma coisa que me convence que isto não é mera convergência de palavras de origens diversas, é que a mesma associação existe entre os equivalentes castelhanos. O bicho chama-se *cernícalo*, que a [Real Academia Española (ERA)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8MBEPpQ) diz vir do latim “*cerniculum* ‘criba’", que significa ‘crivo, peneira’. E a técnica de voar parado é *cerner* ([RAE 7](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8M0MAxV)), que também significa ‘peneirar (farinha, etc.)’ ([RAE 1](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8M0MAxV)). O [Oxford Spanish Dictionary](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cernicalo) explica a origem do nome *cernícalo* precisamente pela “comparação do movimento da ave quando se peneira no ar com o agitar da peneira”; enquanto que [este site](http://www.zepaurban.com/en/actualidad_/noticias/kestrel-%E2%80%9Ctreasure-spanish-language%E2%80%9D-sebasti%C3%A1n-de-covarrubias-y-orozco) prefere comparar com “uma pessoa que peneira” (minha tradução em ambos os casos). Na prática, nem fará muito sentido diferenciar os dois movimentos: o movimento do traseiro do peneirador simplesmente contrabalança o movimento da peneira.

Podem ver peneirar [um peneireiro aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_03F49thJ6s) e [uma padeira aqui.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siJ8QmP4Zx0)

### Peneiras (‘vaidade, presunção’)

Esta aceção de *peneiras* vem com certeza da expressão ***ter peneiras nos olhos***, que eu não conhecia, mas que vem nalguns dicionários e que significa “[v]er confusamente ou mal, não perceber o que é claro; estar cheio de ilusões” ([*Enciclopédia *Brasileira *Mérito, 1967](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qdEPAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Ter%20peneiras%20nos%20olhos.%20Ver%20confusamente%20ou%20mal%22&dq=%22Ter%20peneiras%20nos%20olhos.%20Ver%20confusamente%20ou%20mal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4prmBpebfAhUltlkKHbcgB90Q6AEIKjAA)). A aceção ‘vaidade, presunção’ pode vir simplesmente de ‘ter ilusões acerca de si mesmo; pensar que é muito melhor do que realmente é’.

Naturalmente que quem olha através duma peneira não vai ver muito bem. Esta ideia é antiga. Já em 1720, Raphael Bluteau ([*Vocabulário Portuguez e Latino*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YfMwXg7LS3wC&pg=PA391&dq=%22aro%20de%20pineira%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkos-AxevfAhWHjJAKHSZ7BBQQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22aro%20de%20pineira%22&f=false)) regista o adágio “bem cego he quem muito vé por aro de pineira”. Em 1789, António Moraes ([*Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KvFj2p9f8RgC&pg=RA1-PA182&lpg=RA1-PA182&dq=%22Ver%20por%20peneiras%22&source=bl&ots=-2Ylt_edRm&sig=t7EviCJvuQ_bhjhM3XTyTVsXSuw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP-rrtxevfAhVy7OAKHVqeAQMQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Ver%20por%20peneiras%22&f=false) regista ***ver por peneiras***, “i. e. obscura, e confusamente”.

Note-se que, tal como no uso atual, já temos aqui *peneiras*, no plural, possivelmente porque é uma para cada olho. A partir de 1850 passamos a encontrar na imprensa ***ter peneiras nos olhos***, que aparece na *Enciclopédia Brasileira Mérito* (1967) juntamente com *peneiras* com basicamente o significado que eu conhecia:

> *S.f.pl.* Bazófia, presunção, febre […] *Ter peneiras nos olhos*. Ver confusamente ou mal, não perceber o que é claro; estar cheio de ilusões. / *Tirar as peneiras de alguém*. Elucidar alguém desfazendo-lhe ilusões, fazendo-o ver claro.
>   [*Enciclopédia Brasileira Mérito*, vol, 15, 1967](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qdEPAQAAIAAJ&q=peneiras&dq=peneiras&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi98-aYo-bfAhVCF5AKHSfjCMI4eBDoAQhIMAU), mais [segundo excerto para completar.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qdEPAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Ter%20peneiras%20nos%20olhos.%20Ver%20confusamente%20ou%20mal%22&dq=%22Ter%20peneiras%20nos%20olhos.%20Ver%20confusamente%20ou%20mal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4prmBpebfAhUltlkKHbcgB90Q6AEIKjAA)

A associação mais clara que eu vi entre *ter peneiras nos olhos* e *peneiras* enquanto ‘presunção’ foi num artigo sobre tradições dos Açores:

> […] a um indivíduo todo baboso e presunçoso diz-se ter peneiras ou andar com peneiras nos olhos.
>   [Ferreira Moreno, “Recordando Peneiras”, *Portuguese Times*, New Bedford, Mass., 11 de junho de 2014, p. 26.](https://www.portuguesetimes.com/admin/archive/Edicao%202242.pdf)

Mas já em meados do século XIX se encontram usos da expressão que prenunciam o significado ‘presunção’, como por exemplo nesta notícia que reproduz algumas coplas da comédia *Olho vivo! Companhia de seguros contra as peneiras nos olhos* (negrito meu)

> Vêde o velho, por falta de tino,
>   Que aos oitenta a casar ainda vem,
>   Se depois diz que é pai do menino,
>   É ***peneira* nos olhos** que tem.
>
> A beata que d’homens se espanta,
>   Que aos devotos sómente quer bem,
>   Quando julga que passa por santa
>   Tem ***peneira* nos olhos** tambem.
>
> O safado orador que se mata
>   Sem chamar a attenção de ninguem,
>   Quando pensa ter lingua de prata
>   É ***peneira* nos olhos** que tem.
>   [“Correspondência do Diario Lisboa, 13-4-1854”, *Diario do Rio de Janeiro*, 10 de maio de 1854, p. 1.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=094170_01&pesq=peneiras%20nos%20olhos&pasta=ano%20185)